# Programmatic Auto Layout Issue iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

Seeing some strange behavior in iOS 8.0 concerning auto layout behavior and was looking for any tips or helps on how to solve this problem. I have a UIView that contains another UIView as a subView which contains two labels. The constraints for these labels are added programatically as follows:

```
    //StreamCaptionTextView.m
    - (void)updateConstraints
    {
      NSDictionary *views = @{
                              @"title"   : self.titleLabel,
                              @"desc"    : self.descLabel
                              };

      NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                                @"top"    : @0,
                                @"middle" : @(-2)
                                };

      [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[title]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
      [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[desc]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
      [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-top-[title]-middle-[desc(==title)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

      [super updateConstraints];
    }
```

The parent view of this labelView has constraints in place for the labelView as well.

```
//StreamCaptionView which contains the StreamCaptionTextView
- (void)updateConstraints
{
  [self removeConstraints:self.constraints];

  NSMutableDictionary *views = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
                                                                                 @"image"    : self.profileImageBtn,
                                                                                 @"leftView" : self.leftText
                                                                                 }];
  NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                            @"top"        : @6,
                            @"left"       : @8,
                            @"imageSize"  : @24,
                            @"marginText" : @10,
                            @"maxWidth"   : @120
                            };

  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-top-[image(imageSize)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
  [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-top-[leftView]-top-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

  if(self.rightAcessoryView)
  {
    views[@"rightView"] = self.rightAcessoryView ;
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-left-[image(imageSize)]-2-[leftView]-10-[rightView(maxWidth)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-top-[rightView]-top-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
  }
  else
  {
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-marginText-[image(imageSize)]-2-[leftView]-marginText-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
  }

  [super updateConstraints];
}


//This is the View that contains the captionView
- (void)setVo:(RecordingStreamItemVO *)vo
    {
      _vo = vo;

      __weak RecordingDetailVideoView *_self = self;

      self.captionView.title            = vo.user.screenname;
      self.captionView.subTitle         = vo.title;
      self.captionView.profileImageURL  = vo.user.pictureURL;

      //Here, the captionView is the rectangular blur, inside of the
      //captionView is another UIView that contains the UILabels.

    }
```

For some reason, only on iOS 8.0 the labels are not getting properly rendered in the labelView. This works properly on iOS 8.1 and 7.1 etc. I've tried invalidating the constraints with [self.labelView setNeedsUpdateConstraints] but this doesn't seem to 
fix the problem. I've googled this quite a bit and I've seen other people have autoLayout issues with iOS 8.0 but would like to validate if this is an iOS issue and any potential workarounds I can implement.

[image: Labels Rendering][image: Labels Not Rendering]

//Here are some photos showing what this looks like in the Xcode Visual Debugger

//The first photo is on iOS 8.1 which is working properly

[image]

//This photo is on iOS 8.0 which seems to be ignoring the constraint.

[image]

//ios 8.0

```
layer = <CALayer: 0x17396c90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <StreamCaptionView: 0x15f1fe10; frame = (0 146; 320 35); layer = <CALayer: 0x15f2b3e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x15fcc240; frame = (10 6; 24 24); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15fcc340>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1700d1c0; frame = (0 0; 24 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700d240>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <StreamCaptionTextView: 0x15fcc410; frame = (36 6; 274 23); layer = <CALayer: 0x15f2f620>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MarqueeLabel: 0x15f2f650; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (0 0; 274 13.5); text = 'test1'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x15f200b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x17378d20; frame = (0 0; 26 0); text = 'test1'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 700; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b8960>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17378de0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x173906b0; frame = (45 0; 22 0); text = 'test1'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 701; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b8a60>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17390770>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MarqueeLabel: 0x17390c40; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (0 11.5; 274 13.5); text = 'Test'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17390d60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x17390940; frame = (0 0; 17 0); text = 'Test'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 700; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b93a0>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17390a00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x173a1640; frame = (82 0; 48 0); text = 'Test'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 701; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b94a0>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x173a1700>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x173ae010; frame = (15 179.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x173ad1d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TimePublishedDetailView: 0x173a1d60; frame = (238.5 20; 71.5 11); layer = <CALayer: 0x173a1ef0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x173a21e0; frame = (0 0; 9 9); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x173a2260>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x173a85d0; frame = (16 -2; 55.5 13.5); text = '5 hours ago'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x173a8550>>
```

**Update:**

I actually solved this in the parent view controller with a very simple fix.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  [self.view addSubview:self.detailsView];
  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self loadDetails];

  [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; //This fixed the iOS 8.0 problem

}

//In my case the self.detailsView property contains the view hierarchy which 
//contains the UILabels that weren't being rendered properly way down
//in the view hierarchy. calling layoutIfNeeded fixes this problem for me.
```

Comment: I know this is not what you're looking for but ever tried one of this? https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout It really simplifies the process of writing constraints and make its much more intuitive for anyone reading them

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using View Debugger? You should be able to see what exactly is going on, how view is positioned and what constraints are playing

Comment: @sha I've included some photos of the visual debugger that Xcode has. I can see that in iOS 8.0 the Constraint position is different then in 8.1.

Comment: I think there is known issue that `removeConstraints` is not working properly is iOS8.0  Can you try to modify your code to setup constraints before hand and just modify them in run-time?

Comment: I notice your labels have 0 height. Perhaps the problem lies there. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know exactly what's happening. Pause the app at a convenient point and enter the following command in the console:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

If this doesn't help you straight away try to post it here as a reference for us at least.

Usually doing manual layouts leads to layouts being either under- or over constrained while Interface Builder would warn you for that. For me without more extensive debugging information I am still flying a bit blind.

Now I have those logs I notice the following lines:

```
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x17378d20; frame = (0 0; 26 0); text = 'test1'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 700; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b8960>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17378de0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x173906b0; frame = (45 0; 22 0); text = 'test1'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 701; animations = { position=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x173b8a60>; }; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17390770>>
```

So all labels don't seem to have height.

This line could be off:

```
@"V:|-top-[title]-middle-[desc(==title)]"
```

It doesn't seem to click to the bottom so it can't give the title height nor the desc? Try doing something like this:

```
@"V:|-top-[title]-middle-[desc(==title)]-|"
```

Or give a minimum height:

```
@"V:|-top-[title(>=10)]-middle-[desc(==title)]"
```

Comment: It should be the line in the else statement below the if(self.rightAccessoryView)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions I tried both but unfortunately they did not solve my problem. This view hierarchy is pretty complex and there are a lot of parts to it. I realize that this is just a small snippet of a much larger picture. One thing I did notice is that in my viewDidLoad I load all properties for this view hierarchy. However, navigating to another view controller and back will trigger viewWillAppear instead, and the labels will be loaded correctly on iOS 8.0 in this scenario. I'm not sure if this is much help.

Comment: What's the difference in the visual tree when you do a recursiveDescription when it's wrong and when it works after viewWillAppear?